# Python: How to print object attributes based on user input

Tags: python, input

Goal: I want to return a attribute from a class based on user input.

Specifically, I have created a class for fotballclubs and added some teams. I want to ask the user what his favorite team is, and then print a attribute from his favorite team, for example the best player from that team.

So if the user inputs "Liverpool", I need to match that answer with "Liverpool" from my fotballclub class, and return the bestplayer attribute.

Something like this:

```
class Club:

    def __init__(self, name, kitcolor, bestplayer):
        self.name = name
        self.kitcolor = kitcolor
        self.bestplayer = bestplayer

Liverpool = Club("Liverpool", "red", "Salah")
Chelsea = Club("Chelsea", "blue", "Azpilicueta")

favorite_team = input("What is your favorite team in Premier League?")

EXAMPLE print("The best player of your favorite team is " + Liverpool.bestplayer)
```

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: You can do a mapping of possible names or abbreviations to an object. Or having a list of teams (in this case: `teams = [Liverpool, Chelsea]`), iterate through it and get team by matching name. Then on the found (returned from some search function you write) object you just do `.bestplayer`.

Answer (score 0):

One simple way is to put the instances in a dictionary:

```py
name2club = {}

# create Clubs

name2club[Liverpool.name] = Liverpool
name2club[Chelsea.club] = Chelsea

favorite_team = input("What is your favorite team in Premier League?")

print(f"The best player of your favorite team is {name2club[favorite_team].bestplayer}.")
```

It can be more convenient if the dictionary is a class attribute:

```py
class Club:

    name2club = {}

    def __init__(self, name, kitcolor, bestplayer):
        self.name = name
        self.kitcolor = kitcolor
        self.bestplayer = bestplayer
        self.name2club[name] = self

Liverpool = Club("Liverpool", "red", "Salah")
Chelsea = Club("Chelsea", "blue", "Azpilicueta")

favorite_team = input("What is your favorite team in Premier League?")
print(f"The best player of your favorite team is {Club.name2club[favorite_team].bestplayer}.")
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer me. As I commented on the other answer, this also works fine for clubs with single names, aka Liverpool. However, its a problem with teams like Manchester United, which must be written Manchester_United to be accepted. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

You can use eval to get the object in runtime.
When the object no exist, it will raise "NameError" error.

```
class Club:

    def __init__(self, name, kitcolor, bestplayer):
        self.name = name
        self.kitcolor = kitcolor
        self.bestplayer = bestplayer

Liverpool = Club("Liverpool", "red", "Salah")
Chelsea = Club("Chelsea", "blue", "Azpilicueta")

favorite_team = input("What is your favorite team in Premier League?")
try:
  print("The best player of your favorite team is " + eval(favorite_team).bestplayer)
except NameError:
  print(favorite_team + " data not in this program")
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Both this and the other comment here works, but I find a problem with teams with split names. For example, Manchester United must be written Manchester_United to be accepted as a class, but then it wont be recognised if the user inputs "Manchester United".

Comment: You can replace the space to "_" nafter input.
For explame: `favorite_team = favorite_team.replace(" ", "_")`